# Azure Site Recovery guarantees a two-hour Recovery Time Objective for Azure-to-Azure Failover. For any type of workload?

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

The SLA states [For each Protected Instance configured for Azure-to-Azure Failover, we guarantee a two-hour Recovery Time Objective](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/legal/sla/site-recovery/v1_2/)

I then [read something contradictory on a Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2018/05/02/understanding-rpo-and-rto-considerations-of-azure-solutions/) - From a design perspective it is nearly impossible to guarantee specific RPOs and RTOs for these type of solutions because many variables are outside of your control..When designing for RTO it is important to understand the variables that are not always in your control.  For example, if someone initiates a restore, the time it takes to be back up and running is dependent on variables like the size of the restore, available network bandwidth, speed of the disk drives/VMs, etc.

Can any service (not just ASR) guarantee specific RPOs and RTOs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question

Comment: The important confirmation that I'm looking for is can specific RPO and RTO be guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the supported configurations mentioned in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-support-matrix#deployment-method-support) ,ASR guarantees 2 hour recovery. However, there are some limitations where specified SLA is not applicable.Here are the [limitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKFmI.png) .

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your attempt to offer support to your customers; but please understand that this is not really an acceptable use of this site.  For more information, see the [help] and eventually perhaps turn to [meta] if you need clarifications of our model.

Comment: Also, images of text are [discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) if not outright despised.